# ng-change Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

My code doesn't work, but it is very simple, i copied from an example (http://www.tilcode.com/angularjs-infinite-list-tutorial/):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Produtos: </label>
<div>
    <li data-ng-repeat="produto in prodPromocao track by $index">
        <input name="product" type="text" data-ng-model="prodPromocao[$index]" data-ng-change="addProd($index)" class="form-control">
        <a href="" data-ng-show="produto" data-ng-click="prodPromocao.splice($index,1)">
        [Remove]</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.prodPromocao = [''];
var addProd = function (index) {
    console.log(index);
    if (index == $scope.prodPromocao.length - 1) {
        $scope.prodPromocao.push('');
    }
}
```

Actually, this function addProd is not even called.

Comment: defin `addProd ` function in scope `$scope.addProd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-change` function should be defined on `$scope`

```
$scope.addProd = function (index) {
    console.log(index);
    if (index == $scope.prodPromocao.length - 1) {
        $scope.prodPromocao.push('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg dude! Thanks! I was stuck in this problem for days hahaha

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept as answer if it helped you :) @Ace

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.prodPromocao = [''];
$scope.addProd = function (index) {
    console.log(index);
    if (index === $scope.prodPromocao.length - 1) {
        $scope.prodPromocao.push('');
    }
}
```